# How would I align images across a page in this order: left, middle, right when I have 3 different images?

Tags: image

Aspirations

```
body {
        font-family:Serif;
        background-color:Crimson; 
}

h1 {
        font-family:Serif;
        color:papayawhip;
        text-align: center;
}

p {
        font-family: Serif;
        text-align: left;
        font-size:30px;
        color:papayawhip;
}
```

## Aspirations

I have always wanted to code cool apps and websites and apps which is why I am taking this class. I am really into technology and computers. I want to pursue computer science in college and one day work for big companies like Google, Apple, or Microsoft. Even if I do not get to work at any of those companies, I would still want to be happy and pursue something that I am passionate about and love to do.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/2000px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" alt="Apple" width=150px height=150px>

<img src="http://mobilemarketingwatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/microsoft.png" alt="Microsoft" width=150px height=150px>

<img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" alt="Google" width=150px height=150px>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what your asking for but would adding style="float:left;clear:none;" on all your images suffice for your issue. Might want to be more clear with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this documentation of [inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp).

so your code will most likely be

`.img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}`